# Attribute type is not rendered in Angularjs when it is type="text"

Tags: angularjs, input

I have a very strange issue in  AngularJs application. It is about rendering am input field with the `type="text"`. The issue is that each time I would like to have an input with type text, its attribute type is somehow "magically" is not rendered.

For example this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type=text">
<input type="password" placeholder="Type=password">
<input type="email" placeholder="Type=email">
```

is rendered as:

```
<input placeholder="Type=text"> 
<input type="password" placeholder="Type=password"> 
<input type="email" placeholder="Type=email">
```

[image]

As you can see everything is rendered correctly, but `input[type=text]`

**UPDATE**

It can render anything, but `type="text"`

```
<input placeholder="Type=text"> 
<input type="password" placeholder="Type=password"> 
<input type="email" placeholder="Type=email"> 
<input type="number" placeholder="Type=number"> 
<input type="custom" placeholder="Type=custom"> 
<input type="sdfgsd" placeholder="Type=sdfgsd">
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it inside a JSFiddle or similar? `type="text"` is rendered for me.

Comment: My guess is that this has more to do with the browser default type for input elements. In a sense: "If it's the default, there is no need to type it out"

Comment: At least in [plnkr sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/659baiXw2xSHNvwBcRys?p=preview) it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not even related to AngularJs, in fact it is related to Javascript-based HTML minifier [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier).

Changing `removeRedundantAttributes` to `false` in the `html-minified` config solves the issue:

```
htmlmin: {
  removeRedundantAttributes: false
}
```

Detail are [in this github issue](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/issues/105)